# How to get all the extensions of an url address given the base url address?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, network-security

Is there a way to know all the extensions of a url?

For example let's say there is a website called `www.blabla.com`

and there is another page `www.blabla.com/blabla2.html`.

Is there a way to know `www.blabla.com/blabla2.html` from `www.blabla.com` only?

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible. Because the names behind the main domain
are mostly complete virtual. 
Means the resource behind that name must not be a concrete file
or a concrete web page

You can't know it until you visited each url at least for one time. 
Than the WebCrawler mention by another answer makes sense.

My answer also implies that there is now malware to checkout whats goin on.

Look at the Unix wget. This offers some nice possibilities.

Comment: +1 for bringing up wget.  Wikipedia has some a really nice description of its capabilities and considerations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget#Recursive_download

Comment: @thesquaregroot thx for you agreement. The link you have given me looks good to me, especially cause of its name. Even though i don't think it works properly within secured networks.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is a web crawler: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler

At a high level, you request the base page and then request all of the pages linked on that page.  Continuing this process should yield all of the URLs that are referenced on the website.  However, if www.blabla.com/blabla2.html is real page but is never actually linked to on the website, this process would not find it.